# Firebase & Angular: old data being shown on screen when switching page

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an Angular app with a Home page where I show the 4 latest rows in the "test" Firebase collection. Then there's a separate Test page where I show all rows in this collection. However, when I start on the Home page and then go to the Test page, I still see the 4 latest rows on the screen instead of all the rows.

Here's my code for the home.page.ts:

```
  // Function to load all data required to show on the page
  async loadData() {
    const orderParamsDateDesc = {
      field: 'date',
      order: 'desc'
    }
    
    await this._FirebaseService.readSortLimit('test', orderParamsDateDesc, 4).then(result => this.testRows= result);
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    // Only try to load the data if the user is authenticated again
    this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
      await this.loadData();
    })
  }
```

Here's the same code for the test.page.ts:

```
  // Function to get the transaction rows and calculate the current total P/L
  async getRows() {
    this.testRows = [];
    let orderParams = {
      field: 'date',
      order: 'desc'
    }
    await this._FirebaseService.readSort("test", orderParams).then(result => this.testRows = result);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
      this.getRows();
    })
  }
```

Here is my firebase.service.ts with the readSort and readSortLimit functions:

```
  readSortLimit(collection, orderDetails, limitNumber) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let result = [];
      this.firestore
        .collection(collection, ref => ref
          .orderBy(orderDetails.field, orderDetails.order)
          .limit(limitNumber)
        )
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(item => {
          Array.from(item).forEach(row => {
            result.push(row.payload.doc.data());
          });
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }

  readSort(collection, orderDetails) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let result = [];
      this.firestore
        .collection(collection, ref => ref
          .orderBy(orderDetails.field, orderDetails.order)
        )
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(item => {
          Array.from(item).forEach(row => {
            result.push(row.payload.doc.data());
          });
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }
```